# Which of these CSS selectors "cancel" each other out?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I found a neat example of [Showing Hyperlink Cues with CSS](http://www.askthecssguy.com/2006/12/showing_hyperlink_cues_with_cs_1.html). But in the CSS of the example, there are three separate styles that in  my head should do mostly the same thing. Or at least, I should not have to use all of them in my opinion. But I'm not sure I get them all. Here they are:

```
/* all A tags whose REL attribute equals pdf */
a[rel='pdf'] { 
    padding-right: 18px;
    background: transparent url(icon_pdf.gif) no-repeat center right;
}

/*  all A tags whose REL attributes has the letters pdf somewhere mixed in*/
a[rel*='pdf'] { 
    padding-right: 18px;
    background: transparent url(icon_pdf.gif) no-repeat center right;
}

/* all A tags whose REL attribute contains the value pdf, seperated from other values with a space */
a[rel~='pdf'] { 
    padding-right: 18px;
    background: transparent url(icon_pdf.gif) no-repeat center right;
}
```

I'm thinking I can possible replace the first two with the last one, but again, I'm not 100% sure I understand how these works. Anyone care to shed some light on this?

My question is concretely this: Can I skip one or two of these and still get the same result on all my links?

Comment: So, what's the question exactly?

Comment: @Harmen: Updating the question to clearify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would almost make Venn diagrams of it...

> All `rel='pdf'` are overruled by `rel~='pdf'`
>
> All `rel~='pdf'` are overruled by `rel*='pdf'`

For example:

- `[rel*='pdf']` will style `rel="pdfdoc"`, while `[rel~='pdf']` and `[rel*='pdf']`
  will not
- Both `[rel*='pdf']` and `[rel~='pdf']` will style `rel="pdf doc"`, while `[rel='pdf']`
  will not
- All selectors will style `rel="pdf"`

Not all browsers can handle these CSS3 selectors, I think that's why `rel='pdf'` was added. You could remove `rel*='pdf'` if you don't want to style links that contain `pdf` in the `rel` attribute.

Comment: Smart. Thinking Venn diagrams made the whole thing pretty obvious actually!

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance, the second one should also cover the first and third. But the problem is that there might be a browser that doesn't support the second version and thus needs the first one.

But why would you want these three? If the first should work, then stick with that one. If that one isn't supported, the others won't be supported for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This one covers all use cases:

```
/*  all A tags whose REL attributes has the letters pdf somewhere mixed in*/
a[rel*='pdf'] { 
    padding-right: 18px;
    background: transparent url(icon_pdf.gif) no-repeat center right;
}
```

Since it matches `pdf` anywhere in the text.

Comment: This means it would match for exampe `rel="pdf-document"` as well then I suppose?

Comment: Bear in mind that if you include all three selectors in the same rule, *the entire rule will be ignored* if a browser doesn't recognize **any one** of the selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock: Not sure what you mean now. The entire rule will be ignored? If no elements matches any of them, isn't that kind of the point? Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Svish: If elements match any of them but the browser doesn't understand the others, the browser won't apply the styles. So for example `<a rel="pdf">` wouldn't get the styles on old versions of Opera (*just an example*) even though it matches, because they don't recognize `*=`.

Comment: @BoltClock: Aaah, so I guess that was why it was split up like that then.